# passing data between pages in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have looked at this post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582781/how-to-pass-and-get-parameters-between-two-pages-in-jquery-mobile) and it looks like a simple way of getting a querystring, but Is there a easy way of doing this with the jquery mobile framework? thanks for any advice

```
#MobileHomePage?param1=data&param2=data1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing data between pages with jQuery Mobile is very simple just use this function

```
$.urlParam = function(name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
}
```

for  multi-page template use the following code :

```
$('#myPage').live('pageshow', function(event, ui) {
    var param = $.urlParam('param1');
    alert(param);
});
```

And for a normal template use :

```
    var param = $.urlParam('param1');
    alert(param);
```

And call the page like that :

```
www.yourwebsite.com/mypage?param1=test&gift=Candy etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

make a jquery plugin for this.

```
    (function( $ ){

  $.fn.queryStrings = function( string ) {        

        var url = /[^?]*$/.exec(window.location.href)[0].split('&');

        var obj = {};

        url.forEach(function(url) {
            var tup = url.split('=');
            obj[tup[0]] = tup[1];
        });

        if (string) return obj[string];

        return obj;
  };
})( jQuery );
```

use like this:

```
$().queryStrings('myparam')
```

or

```
$().queryStrings()
```

to return all

Answer (score -1):

There is currently [no built in way](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2859) of passing data between JQM pages, you can use the approaches outlined in the answers to the question you linked.

You might also want to look at these SO overflow questions

[How-to store variable beetween jQM pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10739051/how-to-store-variable-beetween-jqm-pages/10739127#10739127)

[How to pass button text to another page?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10702952/384985)

If your asking how to navigate to the url you posted then you can just use `$.mobile.changePage("#MobileHomePage?param1=data&param2=data1
");`